# Recover data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made an example of what I need at this link [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/welguri/Q4qJy/5/)

retrieving the code

```
var totalRows = $('#tblCatalogo tbody tr').length;
for(var i=1; i<=totalRows;i++){
    var rs = $('#tblCatalogo tbody tr').children().data('cod');
    $('#result').append(rs);
}
```

Comment: This is not a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){    $('#tblCatalogo tbody tr').find("span[data-cod]").each(function (){

    $('#result').append($(this).data("cod"));
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q4qJy/10/

Comment: this example is being retrieved your text inside the td? I need the value of the attribute data-cod

Comment: Ok. Well, you had a problem of getting the right children and that's what i fixed:) (thought the rest you can accomplish by yourself). Next time you should say/ask exactly what you need to accomplish, it will be much easier.

Comment: I'm newbie on this site. 
made it inside the loop " $('#tblCatalogo tbody tr:nth-child(1) span:eq(0)').data('cod') "

Comment: updated my answer for another possible solution (i think its more readable than your solution in the comment)

Comment: the solution that you are duplicating the result showed the date-cod, how could I resolve not to dublicar?

Comment: updated. if this solution suits you, please upvote and mark as solution (the v sign).

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/MSc4K/)</kbd>

[.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
$(function () {
    var rs = $('#tblCatalogo td [data-cod]').map(function () { //.map creates array
        return $(this).data('cod'); //return data-cod value
    }).get().join(); //.get() to get array and .join() to convert array to string joined with comma
    $('#result').append(rs);
});
```

`$('#tblCatalogo td [data-cod]')` select element with attribute `data-cod` inside `td` who is inside element with id `tblCatalogo`

Comment: it would be almost the same. 
only that each value that was reculperado the date cod will be calculated then have to pick one at a time to get calculating